# Finding label-specific top features for non-linear classifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest, xgboost

Is there any function that gives the top features of each label in a Random Forest/ XG Boost classifier? The `classifier.feature_importances_` only gives top features for the classifier as a whole.

Looking for something similar to the `classifier.coef_` that gives label-specific top features for SVM and Naive Bayes classifiers in sklearn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
feature_importances = pd.DataFrame(rf.feature_importances_,
                               index = X_train.columns,
                      columns=['importance']).sort_values('importance',ascending=False)
```

Try with this!

Or 1 vs Rest is also an good option but take lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Random Forest / Xgboost or even a simple DecisionTree/ any Tree ensemble is a inherent multi-class classification model. Hence it will predict the multi-class output without using any wrapper ( 1 vs 1 / 1 vs Rest) on top of binary classifier (which is what the logistic regression/SVM/SGDClassifier would do).

Hence, you can get the feature importance for the overall multi-class classification alone and not for individual labels.

If you really want to know the feature importance for individual labels, then use [onevsRest wrapper](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) with decisionTree/ RandomForest/ Xgboost as the estimator. 
This is not the recommended approach because the results could be suboptimal when compared with single decision Tree.

Some examples [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#one-vs-the-rest).